# Form validation is ignored

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am trying to build a custom registration form for a wordpress plugin. I am validating form fields with jquery validation by formvalidator.net

Although, validation error messages appear as they supposed to, form still gets submitted and user registered. Callbacks onError and onSuccess don't seem to work. Here's my form, what am I missing?

```
    <div class="fn-registration-form">
  <form class="form-horizontal registration-form" role="form">

    <div class="reg-form-group">
      <label for="fn_name" class="sr-only">Your Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="fn_name" id="fn_name" value="" placeholder="Your Name" class="reg-form-control" data-validation="required length" data-validation-length="min5" data-validation-error-msg-container="#val-error-div" />
    </div>

    <div class="reg-form-group">
      <label for="fn_email" class="sr-only">Your Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="fn_email" id="fn_email" value="" placeholder="Your Email" class="reg-form-control" data-validation="required email"data-validation-error-msg-container="#val-error-div"/>
    </div>

    <div class="reg-form-group">
      <label for="fn_pass" class="sr-only">Choose Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="fn_pass" id="fn_pass" value="" placeholder="Choose Password" class="reg-form-control" data-validation="required length" data-validation-length="min5" data-validation-error-msg-container="#val-error-div"/>
    </div>

    <?php wp_nonce_field('fn_new_user','fn_new_user_nonce', true, true ); ?>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-new-user" value="Register" />
  </form>

    <div style="text-align: center;" id="val-error-div"></div>
    <div class="indicator">Please wait...</div>
    <div class="alert result-message" id="#name-error-div"></div>
</div>
<script src="<?php echo plugins_url('js/jquery.form-validator.js', __FILE__); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  jQuery.validate({
    lang: 'en',
    validateOnBlur: true,
    scrollToTopOnError: false,
    borderColorOnError: "#a94442",
    borderColorOnSuccess:"#a94442",
    onError: function () {
        $('.result-message').html('ERROR..!');
        return false;
    },
    onSuccess: function(){
        regnewuserval();
        return false; 
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to stop the form from sending data by adding the "onsubmit" event where is the function must return `false` if there are any errors and `true` if not.

Comment: I've edited my code, I am including the validation callbacks from the formvalidator. In the onSuccess callback I call the function to register new user. In the onError callback I return false. However, they don't seem to work correctly because even with validation errors, a new user is still registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a button (instead of input type="submit") and adding the registration code directly in the onSuccess callback instead of a function in an external js file.

This code works and solved my problem:

```
<div class="fn-registration-form">
  <form class="form-horizontal registration-form" role="form" id="fn-reg-form">

    <div class="reg-form-group">
      <label for="fn_name" class="sr-only">Your Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="fn_name" id="fn_name" value="" placeholder="Your Name" class="reg-form-control" data-validation="required length" data-validation-length="min4" data-validation-error-msg-container="#val-error-div" />
    </div>

    <div class="reg-form-group">
      <label for="fn_email" class="sr-only">Your Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="fn_email" id="fn_email" value="" placeholder="Your Email" class="reg-form-control" data-validation="required email"data-validation-error-msg-container="#val-error-div"/>
    </div>

    <div class="reg-form-group">
      <label for="fn_pass" class="sr-only">Choose Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="fn_pass" id="fn_pass" value="" placeholder="Choose Password" class="reg-form-control" data-validation="required length" data-validation-length="min6" data-validation-error-msg-container="#val-error-div"/>
    </div>

    <?php wp_nonce_field('fn_new_user','fn_new_user_nonce', true, true ); ?>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-new-user">Register</button>
  </form> 

    <div style="text-align: center;" id="val-error-div"></div>
    <div class="val-error"></div>
</div>
<script src="<?php echo plugins_url('js/jquery.form-validator.js', __FILE__); ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
jQuery.validate({
    lang: 'en',
    validateOnBlur: true,
    scrollToTopOnError: false,
    onError: function () {
        jQuery('.val-error').html('ERROR: Please check your data');
        return false;
    },
    onSuccess: function(){
        jQuery('.val-error').hide();
         // YOUR CODE GOES HERE
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the developer console to see if you have any errors elsewhere that could be causing problems.

There could also be a conflict with another jquery plugin if this is a wordpress website.

Comment: No unfortunately there are no JS errors or warnings in the console.